# How to align center an image view inside a view pager when the image's width is less than the display's?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-viewpager, android-gravity

I've been dealing with this for a couple of hours. I need some help.
I have this ImageView inside a ViewPager. Every thing is fine except for when the image cannot reach the display width. I want it to center horizontally but no matter what settings I change I can't make it work.

I used Layout params, setRule, ...
Since there is no setGravity for ImageView what approach should I choose? First new a linear or relative layout then add the image view to it? Isn't there a more rational way to get the ImageView align center?

Here is my code inside the ViewPager's Adapter:

> ```
> public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
>     if (context == null)
>         return null;
>     final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
>     if (propertyImagesIDs == null || propertyImagesIDs.length == 0 || context == null) {
>         return null;
>     }
>     new PropertyPhotoProxy().run(new Response.Listener<Photo>() {
>         @Override
>         public void onResponse(Photo photo) {
>             imageView.setImageBitmap(photo.getBitmap());
>             imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
>             ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
>
>         }
>     }, new DefaultErrorListener(), propertyImagesIDs[position]);
>
>     return imageView;
> }
> ```

Here is how the image is aligned in the screen, NO MATTER what settings I change.

[image]

Comment: try this android:scaleType="centerCrop" for the ImageView

Comment: It's worse. It crops the image and fills the whole parent with the cropped image (cropped and scaled also)

Answer (score 0):

```
 ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START
```

is not what you need. It keeps the aspect ratio and try to fill up the dest on at least one between `width` and `height`. You probably want to use `CENTER_INSIDE` or `CENTER_CROP`

Comment: It is fine by me if it fills up either width or height. I just want it to be in the center horizontally (if it fills the height)

Comment: center crop, crops the image, and center_inside, centers the image BOTH vertically and horizontally. I just want horizontally.